# Racket reader where newline is end of statement

Tags: racket

I'm trying to create a new language in Racket where statements are on separate lines. A newline defines the end of a statement and the start of a new one.

I read through the [Create Languages](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/languages.html) chapter of the guide which was very useful but the examples were focused on extending s-exp-like languages. The only option I see is manually writing my own parser for `read` and `read-syntax`.

I was hoping to use [readtables](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/readtables.html) but I don't know if I can. I tried:

```
(make-readtable #f #f 'non-terminating-macro my-read-line-fn)
```

but I don't know if this is much help. I guess I could create a sub-readtable that does things like `read-word`, `read-string` which I dispatch to based on what character `my-read-line-fn` gets.

Is that the best strategy or is there a predefined way of reading until the end of line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to do anything with the readtable. Your lang/reader.rkt can provide your own `read-syntax` that can read/parse however it wants, and presumably stop when it encounters EOL.

One interesting example is [Brainfudge](https://github.com/dyoo/brainfudge). Its concept of a "statement" is a single character, but IIUC also `[` brackets `]`.

See its lang/reader.rkt and parser.rkt for the low-level bits, and then try to understand how that is ultimately evaluated as Racket expressions.

Comment: Thanks for the advice; my simple read/read-syntax implementation seems to work. If I wanted to have some syntax read by Racket's default reader, would the best approach be to parameterize current-readtable with Racket's default readtable and then call read/read-syntax?

Comment: If you're implementing `read` and `read-syntax`, I don't understand why you'd also need to customize the readtable. However if I'm wrong and you do need to, maybe it would work better to make that a separate Stack Overflow question?

Answer (score 1):

You do indeed need to write version of read and read-syntax that parse your language. The readtable is only meant to modify the builtin read, so I suggest that  you take a look at Parser Tools (http://docs.racket-lang.org/parser-tools/index.html), which is tool for writing parsers in the lex/yacc style.

An alternative is to use ragg:

http://www.hashcollision.org/ragg/

Install Ragg using the package manager in DrRacket. Search for ragg in the list of available packages.

Answer (score 1):

Make your own reader.rkt:

```scm
#lang s-exp syntax/module-reader
(test test)
#:read-syntax my-read-syntax
#:read my-read

;; override default read (won't be used but is required)
(define (my-read in) (read-line in))

;; override read-syntax by reading in one string at a time and
;; pass it to statement-string->code to get code as dara and
;; make it syntax with datum->syntax
(define (my-read-syntax in)
  (datum->syntax #f (statement-string->code (read-line in))))

;; This is actually how you want your code
;; to become s-expressions. I imagine that my
;; module has a primitive called code that 
;; interprets the string as is
(define (statement-string->code str)
  (list 'code str))
```

Answer (score -1):

Racket doesn't have "statements", so the concept of newlines ending "statements" is nonsensical.

If your motivation is to reduce or do away with parentheses, I encourage you to use a "standard alternative" reader like [sweet-expressions](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-110/srfi-110.html), rather than making something home-grown.

Comment: If the motivation is that, I agree with you. Also see Honu and Pyret. However the OP's motivation might be to make a line-oriented DSL.

Comment: Yes, that's essentially what I'm doing. This language is closer to Bash than to Racket so I need statements that have side effects and a similar syntax (ie., no parentheses).

Comment: @Christian You should update your question with more details, in that case; nowhere did you say that a custom DSL was your objective, nor did you have examples of the syntax you had in mind, or even what a statement is. I don't have enough information to evaluate whether using the default reader is even right for your situation at all, even though it seems you're gung-ho about that approach, based on your comment to Greg. Right now your question seems to be an XY problem.